# cin.clear() doesn't allow me to make new input

Tags: c++

When i execute this code, and enter a string (of characters) for `n` it doesn't allow me to make a new input even that i call `clear()`. The program finishes and i cannot enter a value in `p`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ios>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,p;
    cin >> n;
    cin.clear();
    cin >> p;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you're providing as input please. A `clear()` is probably not enough, you most likely have to `ignore` some characters.

Comment: You'd better also show what sequence of input you tested that caused problem.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect example for [test cases](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/). A simple `std::cout` statement could diagnose the problem. If `n` isn't the expected output, then you know that the extraction failed.

Comment: I tested it on arbitrary strings and chars

Comment: @J.M Is your answer resolved? Did either of the answers help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter a string of characters and the stream fails to extract those character, you have to `ignore` the remaining characters up until the next line. This is done using `ignore` but with the maximum number of characters as the amount to ignore, and `'\n'` as our delimiter. You also have to check if your input succeeded:

```
if (!(std::cin >> n) || !(std::cin >> p))
{
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Comment: in Andrew Koenig's book "Accelerated C++", it's given an example of using `cin.clear()` where you want to enter input again and you use this function without using `ignore`. How is this possible?

Comment: @J.M What was the example he provided?

Comment: @J.M `while (in >> x)`: When the `while` loop completely finishes, the stream will hit the EOF character (assuming it read `x` successfully each time). Therefore, there will be no more content left to read, so an `ignore` call is not necessary. If you have extra characters in the stream that do not adhere to the formatting requirements of a type, then it makes sense to discard that content by ignoring it. That was the problem indicated by your question. The person in the example *could* have ignored extra possible characters left in the file when the while loop finished, but he decided not to.

Comment: @J.M The `in.clear()` call after the while loop is necessary because the stream state will be set with the appropriate bits after the extraction in the loop finishes. The author doesn't assume that there is invalid data in the stream, he simply extracts and then clears the stream state. Technically something could have gone wrong during extraction like trying to extract a word (like "car") into a `double`. In *that* case ignoring the rest of the input using `cin.ignore(...)` would make sense, but he does not consider that possibility.

Comment: What if the user enters a string of characters instead of integer in `x` ? Then, as it is in my example, you won't be able to enter new input by just calling `in.clear()`. In the book it says that we don't care what causes the `failure state` of the stream, but we just make us sure that we can enter input for the next user. I am really confused right now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45078/discussion-between-0x499602d2-and-j-m)

Answer (score 0):

There are likely still other characters in the buffer which needs to be flushed. Try using `cin.ignore()` as well as `cin.clear()`.

Comment: The EOF character is not the problem.

Comment: @0x499602D2 EOL != EOF

Comment: The "EOL" character is also not the problem as leading whitespace (including newlines) are discarded from the stream during each input operation by default. It's most likely the issue that he has more data in the stream that he has to `ignore`.

Comment: Also, just so you know I didn't downvote. That was someone else.

Comment: lolz, it sucks when a newbie downvotes a reasonable answer without any hints why he downvotes.